# Passing down navigation props from parent to child

Tags: react-native, navigator

I know this has been answered a thousand times, i just can't get it to work. I'm new to Javascript. Thanks in advance for your help!.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Login from './src/Components/Login/Login.js'
import {StackNavigator, TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
import Signup from './src/Components/Signup/Signup.js'
import Router from './src/Components/BodyPages/Router.js'
import Form from './src/Components/Form/Form.js'

const RootStack = StackNavigator(
 {
   Home: {
     screen: Login,
   },
   Signup: {
     screen: Signup,
   },
   Router: {
     screen: Router,
   },
 },
 {
   initialRouteName: 'Home',
   headerMode:'none',
 }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,TouchableOpacity, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import Logo from '../Logo/Logo.js'
import Form from '../Form/Form.js'
import styles from './Login.styles.js'
//onPress={alert:('ok');}
export default class Login extends React.Component {
render()
{
  return(
    <View style= {styles.container}>
    <Logo />
    <Form type= 'Ingresar' type2 = '¡Ingresar con Facebook!' />
    <View style= {styles.signUpView}>
    <Text style= {styles.signUpText}>Todavia no se encuentra registrado?</Text>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Signup')}><Text style= {styles.signUpTextBolded}>Registrese!</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    <View style= {styles.olvidoView}>
    <TouchableOpacity><Text style= {styles.signUpText}>Olvido su contraseña?</Text></TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    </View>
    )
}
}
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import styles from './From.styles.js'
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';


export default class Form extends React.Component
{
  render()
  {
    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput style ={styles.input}
            placeholder = 'E-Mail'
            placeholderTextColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.3)"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
            onSubmitEditing={()=> this.contraseña.focus()} />

            <TextInput style ={styles.input}
            placeholder = 'Contraseña'
            placeholderTextColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.3)"
            underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
            ref={(input) => this.contraseña = input}
            secureTextEntry = {true} />

            <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Router')} style={styles.Button}>
             <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.type}</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
           <TouchableOpacity style={styles.Button2}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.type2}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>


          </View>
      );
  }
}
```

My problem: when i try to get from Form.js to Router.js, i get UNDEFINED IS NOT AN OBJECT (this2.props.navigation.navigate). I believe my mistake is that i need to pass the navigate prop to my files. I mean, where should i place what?

Thank a lot!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Form` isn't part of your navigator, so it won't have the `navigation` prop injected into it. That's why you are getting `undefined`.

Before going into the fix, first you should remove this line from `Form.js`:

```
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
```

It does nothing. My guess is that you think that importing it will somehow give you access to the `navigation` prop, but that's not correct. `react-navigation` works as a HOC (Higher-Order Component) and injects the `navigation` prop into the screens you define in it.

Now for the fix, you have two simple ways to handle this:

1. Pass down your `navigation` prop into the `Form` component in `Login.js`:

   ```
   <Form
     type='Ingresar'
     type2='¡Ingresar con Facebook!'
     navigation={this.props.navigation}
   />
   ```
2. Define your `onPress` action in `Login.js` and pass that down into `Form.js`:

   ```
   // Login.js
   <Form
     type='Ingresar'
     type2='¡Ingresar con Facebook!'
     navigationAction={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Router')}
   />

   // Form.js
   <TouchableOpacity
     onPress={this.props.navigationAction}
     style={styles.Button}
   >
     <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{this.props.type}</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
   ```

Going into other solutions or why is one better than the other would be a completely different discussion and will become clearer as you learn more about JavaScript and React. For now, this should suffice to get you moving along.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time!